# pkgsrc or macports on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, macports

I've used macports for a long time.  But recently I'm considering switch to pkgsrc.  I thought pkgsrc is for NetBSD only so I just ignore it.  But recently I've found out that pkgsrc makes a lot of effort to make its package profile portable accross multiple unices (including Linux, DragonFly BSD, FreeBSD, OpenBSD and Mac OS X）.

pros of pkgsrc:

- more packages
- much stable maintained (NetBSD seems having more manpower of packagers)
- have releases, current and work-in-progress (while Macports is always work-in-progress, no stable release)

pros of macports:

- more customization for Mac OS X

So does anyone have experiences on using pkgsrc on Mac OS X?  I'd like to hear you opinions.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use MacPorts, since I'm used to it and understand where files can be found to subsequently install non-MacPorts applications with dependencies. However, the article [Use the NetBSD excellent pkgsrc packages collection on Mac OS X](http://web.archive.org/web/20100806222909/http://wiki.slicehost.com/doku.php?id=netbsd_pkgsrc_on_mac_os_x) describes using pkgsrc in a contained disk image, so that it doesn't interfere at all with your main OS X installation, and you can move it around from system to system!

I also found [a discussion thread](http://episteme.arstechnica.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/8300945231/m/919002574931) with a positive mention of pkgsrc on 10.5 at least.

This should provide more info to help you make a decision, although it's not a definite vote for either package manager.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on testing pkgsrc, check pkgin (apt like tool for pkgsrc). 
http://imil.net/pkgin/